# Matching two dataframes in scala

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark-sql

I have two RDDs in SCALA and converted those to dataframes.
Now I have two dataframes.One `prodUniqueDF` where I have two columns named `prodid` and `uid`, it is having master data of product

```
scala> prodUniqueDF.printSchema
root
 |-- prodid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- uid: long (nullable = false)
```

Second, `ratingsDF` where I have columns named `prodid`,`custid`,`ratings`

```
scala> ratingsDF.printSchema
root
|-- prodid: string (nullable = true)
|-- custid: string (nullable = true)
|-- ratings: integer (nullable = false)
```

**I want to join the above two and replace the `ratingsDF.prodid` with `prodUniqueDF.uid`  in the `ratingsDF`**

To do this, I first registered them as 'tempTables'

```
prodUniqueDF.registerTempTable("prodUniqueDF")
ratingsDF.registerTempTable("ratingsDF")
```

And I run the code

```
val testSql = sql("SELECT prodUniqueDF.uid, ratingsDF.custid, ratingsDF.ratings FROM prodUniqueDF, ratingsDF WHERE prodUniqueDF.prodid = ratingsDF.prodid")
```

But the error comes as :

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table not found: prodUniqueDF; line 1 pos 66
```

Please help! How can I achieve the join? Is there another method to map RDDs instead?

Comment: My DataFrame knowldge is not great however there is a join method on Dataframes that could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Joining of the DataFrames can easily be achieved, 
Format is

```
 DataFrameA.join(DataFrameB)
```

By default it takes an inner join, but you can also specify the type of join that you want to do and they have APi's for that 
You can look here for more information.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

For replacing the values in an existing column you can take help of withColumn method from the API

It would be something like this:

```
 val newDF = dfA.withColumn("newColumnName", dfB("columnName"))).drop("columnName").withColumnRenamed("newColumnName", "columnName")
```

I think this might do the trick !

Comment: Thanks @Shivansh. I have tried the join joining RDDs ( not sure if `join` will work properly in DF). But it seems problem there is replacing the existing column with new values.

Comment: Any detail example would really help!

Comment: I have updated the answer please take a look . I hope that you have find all the help that you need !

Comment: If it solved your answer @suvojyotic please accept and upvote ! :)